# Cannot connect to Azure Devops maven repo

Tags: android, gradle, azure-devops, build.gradle, azure-artifacts

I have a maven repo in azure that I am trying to use as a dependency in my android project

In my root `build.gradle` I added the maven credentials

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven {
            url 'http://myRepo/_packaging/lib/maven/v1'
            credentials {
                username "AZURE_ARTIFACTS"
                password System.getenv("AZURE_ARTIFACTS_ENV_ACCESS_TOKEN") ?: "${azureArtifactsGradleAccessToken}"
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

In my app build.gradle I add the dependency and then I go to build I get this error when it tries to resolve that dependency

> NEGOTIATE authentication error: No valid credentials provided
> (Mechanism level: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level:
> Failed to find any Kerberos tgt))

I know its that dependency because if I remove it the error goes away

I am able to publish new versions to the maven repo just fine so I know I have the correct credentials, we even tried giving full permissions in Azure and I still get the error.

Anyone know what could be the issue? Did I put the maven information in the correct place?

Answer (score 0):

By reference to this doc: [Publish a Maven artifact using Gradle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/gradle/publish-package-gradle?view=azure-devops), we can set up a sample `build.gradle` file and maven feed, and then click "**Connect to feed**" button to connect it.
[image]
And then we need to follow its guidance to edit the `build.gradle` file and generate a proper PAT to edit the `settings.xml` file.

Thus please follow the doc to setup your `build.gradle` file and then check the result. Also see this doc: [Install a Maven artifact using Gradle in an Azure DevOps Services build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/gradle/pull-package-gradle?view=azure-devops) to create `gradle.properties` file.

Comment: We use a locally hosted version of DevOps so your image is a little different from what I see. It does not tell me to create any `settings.xml` file just add the credentials to `gradle.properties` and add the maven repo information with the username and access token as password like I have above

Comment: If you use Azure DevOps Server 2018 or later, the steps should be the same, please follow [it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/gradle/publish-package-gradle?view=azure-devops-2020) to check the result.

Comment: @tyczj Is this issue resolved? I am facing the same issue.